# Selection Sort in python

Tags: python, sorting

I'm following the pseudocode as given as a part of [an excercise in CLRS](https://atekihcan.github.io/CLRS/E02.02-02/).

> Consider sorting \$n\$ numbers stored in array \$A\$ by first finding the smallest element of \$A\$ and exchanging it with the element in \$A[1]\$. Then find the second smallest element of \$A\$, and exchange it with \$A[2]\$. Continue in this manner for the first \$n-1\$ elements of \$A\$.

```
a = [99, 31, 41, 59, 26, 42, 58]

for i in range(0, len(a)):

    min = a[i]

    for j in range(i, len(a)):

        if a[j] < min:
            min = a[j]
            a[j] = a[i]
            a[i] = min
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/184691/revisions) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

If you want us to evaluate your code in light of the pseudocode, you'll have to provide the pseudocode, too.

That said, it seems like you're doing a lot of extra work. Specifically, whenever you find an `a[j] < min` you're swapping the `a[j]` and `a[i]` values. The description you give of the pseudocode says to find the min, and then swap. That would be a single swap once the `j` loop is done. You might need a separate variable to hold the index of the min, too:

```
if a[j] < min:
    mindex = j
    min = a[j]
```